# Zip lines in a file with a list and iterate

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary where the keys are taken from a list `keys` and the values are lists of lines taken from multiple text files. Let's assume the list `keys` and all the files to be read have the same number of lines.

How can I iterate over the list `keys` and the lines of each file simultaneously? My idea is to use `zip()` but that hasn't worked for me.

I know that I can iterate over lines in a file using:

```
currFile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for line in currFile:
    # Do something
```

And I know that I can iterate over two lists simultaneously with:

```
for foo, bar in zip(foos, bars):
    # Do something
```

But this doesn't work:

```
myDict = {}
keys = [17, 21, 8, 2, ..., 91]
currFile = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
for key, line in zip(keys, currFile):
    myDict[key] = line
```

I could pull all the lines in the file out into a list, zip it, and then run the loop, but that wouldn't be very efficient.

How can I iterate over the list `keys` and lines in a file simultaneously so that zip() gets called dynamically?

Comment: Do you want to create ONE dictionary, mapping line numbers to a list of strings (the lines) or multiple dictionaries, one for each file, where the line number is mapped to the respective line content?

Comment: `enumerate(currFile)` give you line number and line. And use `append()`

Comment: All get downvote - seems we don't understand your question. You have to change it.

Comment: Can `lineNums` be `[2,45,13,56]` ?

Comment: I was wrong: zip(keys, currFile) _does_ work. Perhaps I should delete this question.

Comment: Yes - zip doesn't work. No - don't delete it - your question got 3 upvotes so this question helps someone, maybe it will help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

> want to create a dictionary where the keys are line numbers and the values are lists of lines taken from multiple text files. Let's assume all the files to be read have the same number of lines.

This solution will work with any number of files, this demo will just have two. Content of demo-file `file1`:

```
line0
line1
line2
line3
```

Content of demo-file `file2`:

```
line5
line6
line7
line8
```

Now make a list of your file objects `files` (e.g. `[open('file1','r'), open('file2','r')]`).

```
from collections import defaultdict as ddict
d = ddict(list)
for number,lines in enumerate(zip(*files)):
    for line in lines:
        d[number].append(line)
```

I work with Python3, if you are working with Python2.x use `izip`. Close the files:

```
for file in files:
    file.close()
```

Content of `d`:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['line0\n', 'line5\n'], 1: ['line1\n', 'line6\n'], 2: ['line2\n', 'line7\n'], 3: ['line3\n', 'line8\n']})
```

Comment: As for me it is the nicest solution.

Comment: A few issues: Using variables `x` and `y` is not very good naming since the names are not descriptive at all, and more importantly using `zip` like that causes all the files and all their content to be loaded into memory before being returned. Using `izip` would be a much better choice. (In Python 3 the code will work fine though, since `zip` will return an iterator.) Finally, using a context manager to open and process one file at a time is a better idea since a failure in one file won't result in a complete failure, and files are closed properly.

Comment: Also, using `zip` like that will limit the processing to the smallest file. `izip_longest` is likely the desired solution. Although, as I said, processing one file at a time is, in my opinion, much better so zipping should not be done at all.

Comment: @Sahand Thanks, I used clearer variable names and added that `zip` was meant to be used with Python3. The OP specified that the files will all have the same number of lines, so `izip_longest` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_to_dict(someDict, filename, someNums):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for num, line in enumerate(f):
            if num in someNums:
                if num not in someDict:
                    someDict[num] = []
                someDict[num].append(line)

myDict = {}

lineNums = [2,45,13,56]

add_to_dict(myDict, "file1.txt", lineNums)
add_to_dict(myDict, "file2.txt", lineNums)
```

---

EDIT: you can use also `defaultdict(list)` as [Sahand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228896/sahand) suggest then you don't need

```
if num not in someDict:
    someDict[num] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using `collections.defaultdict` and `enumerate` can work:

EDIT: Probably better to just pass the file names to the function itself:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def lines_to_dictionary(*files):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for file_name in files:
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
                result[line_number].append(line.strip())
    return result


result = lines_to_dictionary('1.csv', '2.csv')

print result[0]  # Prints a list of first lines in all files
print result[1]  # Prints a list of second lines in all files, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard dict and no zip, one file at a time. Could replace the open/close with 'with'. As mentioned, one file at a time might be better for error handling.

```
d = {}
keys = set([k1, k2, ...])
files = [f1, f2, ...]
for f in files:
    ifs = open(f)
    for n, line in enumerate(ifs):
        if n in keys:
            d.setdefault(n, []).append(line)
    ifs.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keys = [1, 2, 3, 4]
files = [open('a'), open('b'), open('c'), open('d')]

for x in zip(keys, *files):
    print x
```

Edit: your original idea is the correct one, just the syntax to expand the list of files was missing.